# access json with search function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was wondering if someone could help me understand how to access data in my json doc.

```
[
    {
        "article":"title",
        "img_thumb":"images/image.png",
        "article_content":"This is content",
        "alt":["keyword", "keyword2"]
    },
    {
        //here's article 2
    }
]
```

When document.ready, I'm executing this function, which works perfectly:

```
var article_populate = function(){
    $.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            var article = "<div class='thumb'><img src='" + val.img_thumb + "' class='img_thumb'><div class='div_btn article' id='" + val.article + "'>" + val.article + "</div></div>";
            $('#srch_rslt').append(article);
        });
    })
}
```

Then if the user clicks on the article title, I want to append the article content from json to the div where the article title is.

**Update**: this is working now.

```
$('#srch_rslt').on('click', '.article_title', function(){
    var get_article = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(get_article);
    $.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if(val.article_id == get_article){
                console.log(val.article_content)
                $('#' + get_article).parent().append(val.article_content);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `article.title` as an id since it can have illegal characters (',", à, é....).

Since your data structure is an array you can get to the data using the index of the clicked article:

`var articleIndex = $(this).index();` 
with this you can get the corresponding data from your json:

`var articleData = data[articleIndex]`

Now you can append the article content:
`$('selector_where_you_want_data').append(articleData.article_content);`

The quick and dirty way is:
`$('selector_where_you_want_data').append(data[$(this).index()].article_content);`

Comment: You were absolutely right, I was using a 2 word title as an id. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `$.getJSON` incorrectly in your second example, whereas you are using it correctly in the first. Compare

```
    $.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data, key, val){
```

versus

```
    $.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
```

**Edit in response to edit of original question:**

You will need to do something like this:

```
$('#srch_rslt').on('click', '.article_title', function(){
    var get_article = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(get_article);

    var article = $(this);
    $.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if(val.article_id == get_article){
                console.log(val.article_content)
                article.parent().append(val.article_content);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Again, as mentioned in the comments, I recommend reading up on how `this` works in JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm, well I figured since I'm using the `id` of a div to search for the article name and subsequently pull the article contents, I wouldn't have to loop through the whole array of objects?

Comment: searching the array while having the exact index is an overkill.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `$.getJSON`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. The success callback doesn't take arguments `(data, key, val)`. I think you may be confused about how the `this` keyword works in JavaScript. Admittedly, it is a somewhat confusing concept at first; you might want to look at e.g. http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/.

Answer (score 0):

val is an array with multiple articles right?
so it seems logical that your call gives undefined for val.article
i your json file article is not the lowest level so it should be something like

val.0.article.search(get_article)

val.1.article.search(get_article)

I'd suggest dumping the content of var to console using console.log(var); to see how to access the data correctly or if the data is loaded properly.